# Login with Facebook SDK not getting email on Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

When login with Facebook SDK email not getting, only getting name and picture.

This is my code:

```
let requestMe : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields" : "id,name,email,picture.width(100).height(100)"])
let connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()
connection.add(requestMe, completionHandler: { (connectn, userresult, error) in
    if let dictData: [String : Any] = userresult as? [String : Any] {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(dictData)

            self.lblUserId.text = dictData["id"] as? String
            self.lblUserName.text = dictData["name"] as? String
            self.lblEmailAddress.text = dictData["email"] as? String
            if let pictureData: [String : Any] = dictData["picture"] as? [String : Any] {
                if let data : [String: Any] = pictureData["data"] as? [String: Any] {
                    print(data)
                    self.fetchImage(url: data["url"] as? String)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, batchEntryName: "me")
connection.start()
```

Comment: can you please post some code?

Comment: the issue might be with the permissions. Add your code so that we can identify the issue.

Comment: let loginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile","email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
            if error == nil {
                let strToken : String = (result?.token.tokenString)!
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  
                    self.getFacebookProfileInfo()
                  
                }
    
            }
      }
        //This code is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let loginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile","email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
        if error == nil {
            let strToken : String = (result?.token.tokenString)!
            print("Easy Solutions Web's FB Token = \(strToken)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.btnFbLogin.titleLabel?.text = "Logout User"
                self.getFacebookProfileInfo()
               //   self.fetchUserProfile()
            }

        }
    }
```

This is worked...